# How do I set the language code for rendering in entity_view()?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, entities

I'm trying to render entities using a Search API callback with [entity_view()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_view/7).

I want to register entities of type **user** in the **full** view mode as if viewed from the Japanese language.  Here is my code:

```
// Explicitly set language to Japanese.
$render = entity_view('user', array(entity_id($type, $item) => $item), 'full', 'ja');
```

However, the output is still in English.

When I visit a user page rendered using the **full** view mode with a Japanese language user account, the page is displayed correctly.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking inside of user_view() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_view/7

That function should be called by entity_view() and it contains a drupal_alter() call. Print out the $build variable that goes into drupal_alter(). Is it using Japanese? Also print it out after the drupal_alter(). Is $build now back to English? If so, some other module is altering the display.